# Hi, I am getting error while making a POST request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Nodejs, MongoDB and Mongoose and while making a POST request I am getting error:
*POST http://localhost:3000/subscribers
Content-Type: application/json
{
"name": "Lucky",
"subscribedToChannel": "Dev Tech"
}*

**Error: {
"message": "Subscriber validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., subscribedToChannel: Path `subscribedToChannel` is required."
}**
The code snippet is mentioned below:

---

server.js

````
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect(mongodb://localhost/subscribers, { useNewUrlParser: true })
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) => console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to Database'))


app.use(express.json())
const subscribersRouter = require('./routes/subscribers')
app.use('/subscribers', subscribersRouter)

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server Started'))```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
routers/subscribers.js

const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Subscriber = require('../models/subscriber')

// Creating one
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const subscriber = new Subscriber({
    name: req.body.name,
    subscribedToChannel: req.body.subscribedToChannel
  })
  try {
    const newSubscriber = await subscriber.save()
    res.status(201).json(newSubscriber)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})


module.exports = router
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
models/subscriber.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const subscriberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  subscribedToChannel: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  subscribeDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Subscriber', subscriberSchema)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHf38.jpg
````

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHf38.jpg

Click on the link to get the error screenshot

Comment: Code looks good to me, how are you making the request? What's the value of `req.body` in that route?

Answer (score 0):

Use bodyParser above app.use(express.json())

Like : app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended : false }))